# How can I send information about router endpoints to peers

Tags: c++, ipc, zeromq

I'm writing IPC for a set of programs. Router starts on any free endpoint i.e. `"tcp://127.0.0.1:*"`. Then I can get endpoint to which router was bound with `zmq-getsockopt` and `ZMQ_LAST_ENDPOINT`. But now I need a way to give this information to clients.
I already tried to use shared memory for this (QSharedMemory). And that worked on Windows and MacOS, but not in appstore (sandbox problems). I'm pretty sure I will be able to make some workarounds and make it work. But I kind of don't like this solution anyway. And for me it seems like it must be a common problem, maybe even with common simple and reliable solition. Unfortunately, I can't find anything on google.

A little info about this IPC.
All clients talk to each other only through router. On start client checks if router already running or not, if not - client starts router. Then client tries to get endpoints from router, and then connects to them.

I'm not sure what information can be helpful here, so I will answer all questions.

EDIT:
A little more context.
[image: I hope somewhat helpful graph]

In router I have this setup

```
zmqpp::socket back(context, zmqpp::socket_type::xreq);
back.bind("inproc://backend");
zmqpp::socket front(context, zmqpp::socket_type::xrep);
front.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:*");
zmqpp::socket worker(context, zmqpp::socket_type::xreq);
worker.connect("inproc://backend");

/// m_lastEndpoint value I need to send to peers
front->get(zmqpp::socket_option::last_endpoint, m_lastEndpoint);
proxy = std::thread([this]() { zmqpp::proxy(front, back); });

/// Send:
worker.send(msg);
/// Receive:
worker.receive(answer)
```

And in peer I have this setup

```
zmqpp::socket worker(context, zmqpp::socket_type::xreq);
front.bind(ROUTER_ENDPOINT_HERE);

/// Send:
worker.send(msg);
/// Receive:
worker.receive(answer)
```

Usage example:

- user starts program1 (for example, Video Editor)
- program1 checks if router running (starts it if necessary).
- program1 receives router endpoints in some way ???
- program1 connects to router. Sends SayHello message. (I'm not going in details here, because I don't think what this is important)
- program1 wants program2 (for example, some sort of Screen Recording software) to make some action.
- program1 sends message to router with something like: `{ "target" : "program2", "action" : "action1" }
- router resends this message to program2
- program2 executes this action

Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand the broad scheme of your application, so maybe a sketch could help. But from what I understood, you are trying to pass the endpoints of all your routers to some clients? Is that correct? Maybe some form of [network discovery](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter8/#Network-Discovery) could help you. As I said before, visually I don't have a clue of what are the pieces involved, but that link could help you, not sure about it.

Comment: @Gealber thank you for this link. I couldn't find immediate solution there. But that was helpful anyway, at least I read about ZeroConf maybe I can use it here. Also, I updated my question with some hopefully helpful sketch + some use case.

Comment: This question isn't really about ZeroMQ but about service discovery and/or inter-process communication on a specific OS/platform. You might get more and better responses if you post a new question focusing on the actual issue and tagging it accordingly.

Comment: Maybe this is an overkilling solution, but you could use Redis as a queue. In a way that you push from the routers to redis the `endpoints`, and later in the clients you pop from that same queue the `endpoints`. In that way, if you decide to add more clients, they just need to consume from this same queue. Of course, if you pop an element from the queue, it won't be available for other clients. But redis has other options that could help also.

Comment: @Gealber, I haven't worked with Redis, but from what I read now, it seems like Redis works on some tcp port, so if I want to get information from Redis database (or what is it) in peer application, I still need to know on which port Redis is started. I may be wrong.